# Can I power multiple devices from a single Centralize Power Supply Adapter?

Tags: power-supply, peltier

I want to power in parallel

- 10 Thermoelectric Cooler Peltier DC12V 3.3Ω [image]
- 2 water pump DC12V 3.7A [image]

using 12 V 40A Centralize Power Supply Adapter [image]

Will this work fine?
Can my power adapter provide good power to my devices?
Please help me... I'm not good at computation

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. One of your peltier devices will consume 12/3.3 A = 3.64A hence 10 of them require 36.36A. The 2 water pumps need 3.7 * 2 = 7.4A. So the total load would be 43.76A which exceeds the rated current of your power supply. I don't know where you are sourcing the supply, but if it's a bargain basement device then I wouldn't run it anywhere near its full rated current let alone try to overload it. Either buy a 50A module or a second supply and share the loads between them.

Comment: thank you Mr. Peter have a nice day